# File name encoding issues

Tags: .net, encoding, zip, filesystems, filenames

System receives a zip file together with a list of file names (inside zip) that should be processed.

Problem: occasional "file not found error".

The file name specified in error message and the one visible in file system are visually identical, therefore it's an encoding issue.
The error does not occur if file open operation is retried with a normalized file name like so:

```
filename.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormD)
```

Current solution is :

```
bool TryProcessFile(string filename) {
    string[] filenamesToTry = new string[] {
        filename,
        filename.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormD)
    }
    foreach (string fname in filenamesToTry) {
        try {
            ProcessFile(fname);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException) {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

function ProcessFile:

```
void ProcessFile(string filename) {
    string fullpath = Path.Combine(this.extractionDir, filename);
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fullpath); // throws file not found
    ...    
}
```

Is there a way to avoid an error in the first place?

In general how to tackle problems like this?

Comment: Please provide more code and the previous processing used.

Comment: Updated description

Comment: How big is the biggest file?

Comment: the max length of an array is 2,147,483,591(Uint32.Max()).
2 Problems here -
1. If the file size is larger than 2,147,483,591 the application will throw an error
2. Based on memory consumption, your storing whole files in memory, thats alot of memory consumption

Comment: File size is not the issue here. 
Last file that caused "file not found error" was 70 KB.
Retrying with a normalized file name string does not throw error.